# how to find a if an array is empty within an array in javascript (angularjs)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, function

I'm currently trying to find if an object property "itemBag" is set in an object.

The issue I am having is that I am getting 2 different arrays from the api and the property "itemBag" is not included within the object so I get an "undefined" error.

**The 2 different arrays that I get:**

Array 1:

```
[
  [
    {
      "orderNumber": 1,
      "itemBag": [
        {
          "size": 10000,
          "name": "hello.pdf",
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
]
```

Array 2:

```
[
  [
    {
      "orderNumber": 1
    }
  ]
]
```

The function that I am using to try to determine if "itemBag" is empty or not:

$scope.reproductions is the array mentioned above

```
$scope.checkFirstDesignContainerIsEmpty = function() {
    var containerIsEmpty;
    if($scope.reproductions[0][0].includes(itemBag)) {
      containerIsEmpty = true;
    }
    return containerIsEmpty;
};
```

I keep getting an error that itemBag is undefined.

Comment: `(parent.childArray || []).length === 0` is a simple way to test if an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is `itemBag` in your function?  It isn't declared before use so of course it is undefined. `$scope.reproductions[0][0]` is also not an array, it is an object, so trying to call array functions like `includes` just won't work.

```
$scope.checkFirstDesignContainerIsEmpty = function() {
    var containerIsEmpty;
    if($scope.reproductions[0][0].includes(itemBag)) { // itemBag hasn't been declared, so is undefined
      containerIsEmpty = true;
    }
    return containerIsEmpty;
};
```

To test if the `$scope.reproductions[0][0]` object doesn't have an `itemBag` property, or if it does and it is empty:

```
$scope.checkFirstDesignContainerIsEmpty = function() {
    var containerIsEmpty = true;

    // test if itemBag key exists and value has truthy length value
    const { itemBag } = $scope.reproductions[0][0];
    if(itemBag && itemBag.length) {
      containerIsEmpty = false;
    }
    return containerIsEmpty;
};
```

Or more succinctly:

```
$scope.checkFirstDesignContainerIsEmpty = function() {
    const { itemBag } = $scope.reproductions[0][0];
    return !(itemBag && itemBag.length);
};
```

Comment: $scope.reproductions is the array mentioned above

Comment: Yes, `$scope.reproductions` is defined, but how you're using [`array::includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) isn't correct.  As written you are searching your reproductions array for a value that matches whatever `itemBag` is, but `itemBag` isn't defined.  It also won't work because `reproductions[0][0]` isn't an array, it's an object.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding quotes around itemBag:

```
$scope.checkFirstDesignContainerIsEmpty = function() {
  var containerIsEmpty;
  if($scope.reproductions[0][0].includes('itemBag')) { // Added quotes here
    containerIsEmpty = true;
  }
  return containerIsEmpty;
};
```

Comment: $scope.reproductions[0][0].includes is not a function is the error that i am getting

Comment: My mistake! You can only use `includes` on an array. When trying to see if an object has a property you have to use `hasOwnProperty`. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty